# conda change python version between 2 and 3

Tags: python, environment, conda

I'm learning using `conda` to control environment of python in windows 10 powershell, following [this doc](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/test-drive.html).

It says the current environment should be shown parentheses or brackets

> Which of these environments are you using right now – snowflakes or
>   bunnies? To find out, type the same command:
>
> conda info --envs
>
> Conda displays the list of all environments, with the current
>   environment shown in (parentheses) or [brackets] in front of your
>   prompt:
>
> (snowflakes)
>
> NOTE: conda also puts an asterisk (*) in front of the active
>   environment in your environment list; see above in “List all
>   environments.”

My questions are: 1. why i don't see parentheses/brackets

2. why `activate python2` does work?

Code at powershell:

> PS C:\Users\yzhang> conda info --envs
>
> conda environments:
>
> python2                  d:\Anaconda3\envs\python2
>
> root                  *  d:\Anaconda3
>
> PS C:\Users\yzhang> activate python2
>
> prepending d:\Anaconda3\envs\python2 and
>   d:\Anaconda3\envs\python2\Library\mingw-w64\bin and
>   d:\Anaconda3\env s\python2\Library\usr\bin and
>   d:\Anaconda3\envs\python2\Library\bin and
>   d:\Anaconda3\envs\python2\Scripts t o PATH
>
> PS C:\Users\yzhang> conda info --envs
>
> conda environments:
>
> python2                  d:\Anaconda3\envs\python2
>
> root                  *  d:\Anaconda3
>
> PS C:\Users\yzhang> python --version
>
> Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)

I've verified there's `python27` in path `d:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\python2`

Answer (score 0):

Full support for `activate`/`deactivate` in Windows PowerShell has not currently been implemented.  There is an open Pull Request at https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/2366 that you may be interested in tracking.

Comment: thanks @kalefranz   the docs says `source` is for Linux and OS X, and i'm using windows 10. I tried `source activate python2`, and it reported `not recognized`

Comment: Oh, I see.  Editing the answer above.